# Prove: Three tangents to a parabola form a triangle with an orthocenter on the directrix and a circumcircle passing through the focus

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

> Prove the following:
>
> The intersection points of any three tangents to a parabola given by the formula $y(y-y_0)=2p(x-x_0)$  are vertices of a triangle whose orthocenter belongs to the directrix of the parabola and the circumcircle of the triangle passes through the focus of the parabola.

---

**My attempt:**

**Orthocenter problem part- edited** (old notes deleted to be less chaotic and I believe there is still some space for improvement of the first part):

In the meantime, I realized it would be better to just use the condition of tangency and plug some of its parameters into the formula for a line in the $xy$ plane.

Let $y=k_ix + l_i,\ i=1,2,3$ be a tangent line to a parabola. Then $$p=2k_il_i\implies l_i=\frac{\frac{p}2}{k_i}$$

Now, our equation becomes:
$$\boxed{y=k_ix+\frac{\frac{p}2}{k_i}}$$
We can substitute $\frac{p}2$ by $\alpha$, so
$$\boxed{y=k_ix+\frac{\alpha}{k_i}}$$
This way, our computations are getting easier.
The equations of the three arbitrary tangents to a parabola are:
$$\begin{aligned}y&=k_1x+\frac{\alpha}{k_1}\\y&=k_2x+\frac{\alpha}{k_2}\\y&=k_3x+\frac{\alpha}{k_3}\end{aligned}$$
The intersection point of the $i-$th and $j-$ th tangent line:
$$k_ix+\frac{\alpha}{k_i}=k_jx+\frac{\alpha}{k_j}\implies x=\alpha\frac{\frac1{k_j}-\frac1{k_i}}{k_i-k_j}=\frac{\alpha}{k_ik_j}$$
$$y=k_i\cdot\frac{\alpha}{k_ik_j}+\frac{\alpha}{k_i}=\alpha\left(\frac1{k_i}+\frac1{k_j}\right)$$
$$\boxed{S_{ij}=\left(\frac{\alpha}{k_ik_j},\alpha\frac{k_i+k_j}{k_ik_j}\right)}$$

Now, we have to find the line perpendicular to the $k-$th tangent line passing through the point $S_{ij}$.
$k_\perp=-\frac1{k_k}$
E.g., one altitude of the formed triangle belongs to the line:
$$\begin{aligned}y-y_{S_{1,2}}&=k_\perp(x-x_{S_{1,2}})\iff &y&=-\frac1{k_3}x+\frac{\alpha}{k_1k_2k_3}+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_2}\right)\\&&y&=-\frac1{k_3}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_2}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)\end{aligned}$$

So, the $x$ coordinate of the intersection of the three tangent lines:
$$\begin{aligned}y&=-\frac1{k_3}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_2}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)\\y&=-\frac1{k_2}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_3}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)\\y&=-\frac1{k_1}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_2}+\frac1{k_3}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}-\frac1{k_3}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_2}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)&=-\frac1{k_2}x+\alpha\left(\frac1{k_1}+\frac1{k_3}+\frac1{k_1k_2k_3}\right)\\\left(\frac1{k_2}-\frac1{k_3}\right)x&=\left(\frac1{k_3}-\frac1{k_2}\right)\alpha\\x&=-\alpha=-\frac{p}2\end{aligned}$$

**End of the first part. The rest remains the same not to be off-topic**.

---

Since the points $P_1,P_2, P_3$ are close to the directrix, $\triangle ABC$ in my picture is obtuse and its orthocenter is outside the triangle, but it doesn't have to be so at all.

Let $A,B,C$ be the intersection points of the tangents. $P_2\in\overline{AC}$ due to $P_1\preceq P_2\preceq P_3$.

Let $A'\in\overline{BC}$ s.t. $AA'\perp BC$, $B'\in\overline{AC}$ s.t. $BB'\perp AC$ and $C'\in\overline{AB}$ s.t. $CC'\perp AB$.

The center $S$ of the circumscribed circle $q$ of $\triangle ABC$ is the intersection point of the bisectors $s_1,s_2,s_3$ of the sides $\overline{AB},\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{AC}$ respectively. Furthermore, $\underline{\text{each side bisector is parallel to one of the sides of the triangle}}$, i.e.,
$$s_1\parallel\overline{AA'}\ \&\ s_2\parallel\overline{BB'}\ \&\ s_3\parallel\overline{CC'} $$

If the orthocenter $T$ is an orthogonal projection of the point $P_2$ onto the directrix $x=-\frac{p}2$ of the parabola, and if the circumscribed circle $q$ really passes through the focus
$$\boxed{F\left(\frac{p}2,0\right)\ \text{or}\ F\left(\frac{p}2+x_0,y_0\right)}$$
then $|TP_2|=|P_2F|$.

**Picture:**
[image]

**zoomed:**
[image: zoomed just in case]
According to the notation in the picture:
$$\begin{aligned}\measuredangle AA'B&=\measuredangle A'CT=\measuredangle BFL\\\measuredangle B'TA&=\measuredangle ACA'=\measuredangle AFB\end{aligned}$$
I can see:
$$\triangle AB'T\sim\triangle BB'C\sim\triangle A'AC\sim AFB'$$
In particular: $\boxed{\triangle AB'T\cong\triangle AFB'\implies\ |TB'|=|B'F|\implies\triangle TFP_2\ \text{is isosceles}\ \implies |TP_2|=|P_2F|\ }$

Also:
we can prove **the orthogonal projections of the focus onto the three tangents belong to the tangent passing through the vertex of the parabola**, meaning those projections are collinear, which, by the [*Simson theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line), implies the focus belongs to the circumcircle of the triangle.

May I ask for advice on solving this task and improve the parts I might have done correctly to be concise as possible? Thank you in advance!

---

**P. S.** I found a [related paper](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/ParaProblems.htm#all), but almost none of the information has been covered in our official literature.

Just in case, I found an [answer by @JeanMarie](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3506121/705917) recalling the fact the orthocenter of the observed triangle lies on the directrix of the parabola, but I couldn't think of proof.

---

**Update on a special case:**

I've also read **the directrix is the set of all the points in the plane we can draw two mutually perpendicular tangents from** (which can be proven via *Vieta's formulae* and the *condition of tangency*). In a right-triangle, the orthocenter is obviously in the vertex opposite to the hypothenuse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that the focus of a parabola lies on the circumcentre of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198512/proving-that-the-focus-of-a-parabola-lies-on-the-circumcentre-of-a-triangle)

Comment: @JeanMarie, I would honestly need time to go through my post and remember what I asked 2 years ago, because I haven't done much elementary geometry since then... Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second request easily follows from this theorem ([see here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651655/a-parabola-touches-the-bisectors-of-the-angles-formed-by-lines-x2y3-0-and-2/3651883#3651883)):

> The exterior angle between any two tangents is equal to the angle
>   which either segment of tangent subtends at the focus.

It follows that $\angle CFP_2=\angle BCA$ and $\angle AFP_2=\angle CAB$, whence:
$$
\angle CFA=\angle BCA+\angle CAB=\pi-\angle ABC.
$$
Focus $F$ lies then on circle $ABC$.

[image]

Comment: (+1) I discovered that this interesting result is called [Lambert theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ThreeParabolaTangents.shtml)

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2198512/305862) and [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/254241/circle-circumscribing-triangle-formed-any-three-tangents-parabola-passes-through-focus) and